# Get path from Uri throws nullpointerexception

Tags: android, image, path, uri

I try to get the path of an image file, but getPath() method returns null (cursor is  null).

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

selectedImageUri = data.getData();

```
                String selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
```

I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Just for a note. In your method `public String getPath(Uri uri)` you have a memory leak because you forgot close your `cursor` when returning a result.

Answer (score 0):

A `Uri` does not have to represent a file on the filesystem that you can access. The `Uri` might point to content that is:

- stored on removable storage, which you cannot access
- stored on internal storage of another app, which you cannot access
- stored in an encrypted form, where a `ContentProvider` needs to decrypt it
- stored in a BLOB column of a SQLite database, where a `ContentProvider` needs to load it and serve it
- stored in "the cloud", where a `ContentProvider` needs to download it
- generated on the fly, the way this Web page is
- and so on

You can use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by the `Uri`. You can create a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control. And, you can use Java I/O to copy from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`, making your own copy of the content in a file that you control.